# Maintain HTML5 Canvas state on postback

Tags: asp.net, html, canvas

I have many HTML5 Canvas elements on my page which users doing stuff on then like drawing and etc. the problem is if any postback happens all canvases would refresh and clear.

I tried putting runat="server" on then to enable viewstate but no help.

```
<canvas runat="server" id="mycanvas" height="233"></canvas>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086357/html5-canvas-got-refersh-after-postback-in-asp-net

Comment: That is the nature of canvas. Canvas content is not retained during postbacks. Perhaps disallow postbacks until the user has finished drawing.  If you want to save the content across postbacks you must serialize the content yourself--perhaps save all the users drawing commands in a hidden element or save the users drawing commands using localstorage.